# Let A be a cone with radius R and height H. A is allowed inside a sphere with radius 1.

Tags: calculus

Find the maximum surface area of C, a cylinder inscribed in A with radius r and height h where the top and bottom disks are removed.
This is my working:
First i find the surface area of sphere which gives rise to 4*pi. The surface area of the cylinder is (2*pi*(H-h)*h*R)/H. How do i continue from here?

Comment: Welcome Jaysoh! This is not clear, at least to me. Is $A$ a cone or a sphere? If it's a cone, where does the sphere come into the problem?

Comment: Hi A is a cone. The cone is now inscribed into a sphere of radius 1.